# Tensorflow - running python files in Spyder

Tags: python, linux, tensorflow, terminal, object-detection

to give a bit of background I'm trying to use TensorFlow object detection api. I have been following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MoMjIwGSFVQ

15 minutes into it he uses Spyder, and runs the python files on it. I've never used Spyder before, and for some reason it's not running my files at all? When I press run nothing is returned on the console.

So can anyone suggest a different IDE that I could use that would allow me to do the same things as he does? Or would anyone be able to tell me why Spyder might not be running. (I installed it in Linux terminal, and simply imported the file as a project as he did, and so I'm a bit stumped as to whats going wrong).

Thanks!

Comment: I haven't found a solution to the spider issue. However, I found a good alternative was PyCharm. I also think atom might be useful for this too.